# Any way to prevent an account from up/down voting or flagging?

Tags: discussion

Is there a badge/status that gives privileges to prevent few accounts from up/down voting posts? What happens if a family/friend/colleague who is a programmer who uses the same machine keeps up/down voting/ flagging just for the fun of it?

Comment: Are they using your account or their own account?

Comment: Their own account.Few of my family members are programmers.

Comment: If they're voting on your content, the votes *could* be reversed, but, if they're just randomly voting on other peoples content there isn't really much that can be done, unless the voting violates policies.   As far as the flagging goes, if they're abusing their privileges moderators probably won't let it go too far before taking action.

Comment: This is one of the main purposes of temporary suspensions.  Locking up the account when there is suspicious activity in an attempt to let the real user regain control of their account.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a badge/status that gives privileges to prevent few accounts from up/down voting posts?

That status is a [diamond](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role).

If someone is abusing their voting privileges to either cheat the system for their personal gain or make someone else's life miserable, flag one of their posts and we'll deal with it. Depending on the severity this may entail suspending their account, preventing them from voting or flagging for the duration of their suspension.

If someone is flagging just for the fun of it, well let's just say they'll learn **very** quickly that flags are not a toy for them to play with.